# How do I count an instance based on 2 conditions that need to be met?

Tags: mysql, sql, count, aggregate-functions, where-clause

I created a schema in MySQL workbench & a table named: "exam"
The table has column names: "Exam_ID", "Start_Time", "Finish_Time", & "Room_ID"

I want to count all the exams that start after 5pm corresponding to each room.

```
SELECT COUNT(`Start_Time`) FROM `exam` WHERE `Start_Time`> '17:00:00' AND `Room_ID` = 'IR1';
SELECT COUNT(`Start_Time`) FROM `exam` WHERE `Start_Time`> '17:00:00' AND `Room_ID` = 'IR2';
SELECT COUNT(`Start_Time`) FROM `exam` WHERE `Start_Time`> '17:00:00' AND `Room_ID` = 'IR2';
```

Here is a sample of what I desire the output to look like
[image: Output]

**How can I count the # of exams correctly based on the conditions**

Answer (score 1):

This looks like filtering and aggregation:

```
select room_id, count(*) as cnt
from exam
where start_time > '17:00:00'
group by room_id
```

Comment: This is wrong. I don't want to group them, I want to count the # of instances for each & output them separately like the picture above. Plus this code does not work.

Comment: @BradleyHerro: what is wrong (or does not work) with the results that this query gives you?